# Does Doctor Strange know about the creation/creator of the Infinity Stones?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, infinity-stones, doctor-strange

Who created the Infinity Stones/how did they come into existence?

Doctor Strange has the Time Stone, so does he know about it? Also does he know about all of the Infinity Stones that exist?

Comment: This is currently asking two questions, how were the stones created and if Doctor Strange knows about them all. Could you [edit] this to only ask one?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot is it good now?

Comment: For the record, there are about twenty different origin stories for the stones _in the comics and other TV shows_.

Answer (score 6):

In the most recent film (Avengers: Infinity War) Wong provides a nice magical hologram show regarding the origin of the Infinity Stones. It seems fair to say that this isn't news to Strange since he helps with narration and correctly identifies them by colour and name.

Later in the film he describes various things that Thanos will be able to do with various of the Stones, indicating that he also knows their powers.

There's also a mini-origin for the Stones in Guardians of the Galaxy